# SVN to Git. New branch with new source

Tags: git, svn, directory

We're moving from SVN to Git.

I setup empty Git repo on our server. Set up a working directory on my local machine and downloaded the complete source from SVN repo to this local folder (Working directory). I pushed all these files to master branch and created two branches, `dev` and `staging`. This is all fine.

Now I want to create a new branch called `v1.0` with completely different source (lot of new features).
My plan is to create a new working directory (local folder) called `v1.0` and import the source (from another SVN repo) to this folder. I want to point this folder to the `v1.0` branch.

Can someone explain steps how this can be done? (I am fairly new to Git)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful not to commit all the `.svn` directories to Git

Comment: Nope. I am just downloading all source files manually and pushing them to git repo. So I am good there. Thanks anyways. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the project is completely different it has more sense to create a separate git repo. The main philosophy change while moving from svn to git is to prefer to have multiple repositories for each logical module (e.g. library, program, etc).

However, if you really want to have a single repo with git, you could create an orphan branch: `git checkout --orphan v1.0`.

Comment: Its not completely different. As I mentioned, there is a lot of new features. Creating a new repo... How do I merge these new features (lets say I created a new repo) with the existing branch? Is it a common scenario?

Comment: Also, the goal is to have a separate `source` / `Working Directory`

Comment: @KevinRave Not sure what do you mean. A working directory of git is your project folder. The git repository is `.git` folder in the folder. With git you usually have one working directory and just switch its content.

Comment: Here is what I did. 1) Setup a folder in local machine. 2) Init Repo 3) created 3 branches. all fine. This folder is a working dir for all these 3 branches (develop, staging, master). Now I created another folder with a different set of files called v1.1. Now I want all these files in a new branch called v1.1. This is all what I need to do. So finally 4 branches. 3 identical branches and 4th one with a different set of files from a different directory. still confusing?

Comment: @KevinRave Why do you create two folders? You could have all branches in the same git repo and in the same working directory.

Comment: @KevinRave Have you tried `git svn`? It will import all svn repo into a git.

Comment: I don't want to import from SVN. I am setting up fresh git repos.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24066/discussion-between-kan-and-kevin-rave)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, that you are currently not at all concerned with keeping the svn-history in your git repository, why not do something as simple as:

```
$ cd project
$ git checkout -b v1.0
$ rm all files not needed
$ # the above could also just be "rm *", just be careful to not delete .git
$ cp -r /path/to/project-1.0/* .
$ git add .
$ commit -a -m "imported v1.0"
```

git should figure out by itself which files have not been touched, or renamed, or ...

and having all in one repository, makes it easy to cherrypick (where this is possible)

Comment: I understand what you are doing. On the 5th line, you are copying all files from a folder to git. But does that make that folder as working directry?

Comment: use `git add --all` to add all changes including deleted/moved files.